# SML Function to "zip together" lists of an arbitrary depth

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, sml

I'm trying to translate a nested for loop in Java code to SML. I'm going to have a list of the format [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]] and I want this function to give me a list of the form [[a, d, g], [b, e, h], [c, f, i]]. The length of each list will vary, and I need to avoid using any mutable datatypes. The code I have so far is this -- the bottom `pointFromList` takes each inner list and drops it into a record that I've defined elsewhere.

The problem I'm having is that the code below doesn't terminate. Looking at debugging output, it works fine through all of the `zipElement ([], xs::xss, accY, accX)` calls, but it breaks somewhere after that. I'm new to SML and I'm completely stumped.

```
fun zipListToPoints (featuress : real list list) = 
    let
    fun zipElement ([], [], accY, []) = 
        accY
      | zipElement ([], [], accY, accX) =      
        zipElement(rev(accX), rev(accY), [], [])
      | zipElement ([], xs::xss, accY, accX) = 
        zipElement([], xss, [hd(xs)]::accY, tl(xs)::accX)
      | zipElement (ys::yss, xs::xss, accY, accX) =
        zipElement (yss, xss, (hd(xs)::ys)::accY, tl(xs)::accX)
    val numFeatures = length(hd(featuress))
    val zippedList = zipElement([], featuress, [], [])
    in
    map pointFromList zippedList
    end
end
```

The larger context is that I have a record type `point` with a label `features : real list`. In order to normalize the data before doing some analysis on it, I need to perform an operation on the ith element of the `features` list for each point. The original Java looks like this:

```
for(i=0;i<Points.length(); i++){
    oneFeature = new float[Points.getNumberOfFeatures()];

    for(j=0; j<Points.getNumberOfFeatures(); j++){
    oneFeature[j] = Points[j].getFeature(i);
    }

    normalizedData = new float[Points.getNumberOfFeatures()];
    normalizedData = normalize(oneFeature);

    for(k=0; k<Points.length(); k++){
    Points[k].setFeatureList(normalizedData[k]);
    }
}
```

and my SML should eventually look like:

```
fun normalizeData (points) =
    let
    fun extractFeature (index) =
        map (fn features => sub(features, index)) #features(points)
    val listOfFeatures = 
        map extractFeature list.Tabulate (length(points), fn x => x)
    val normalizedFeatures = 
        map normalizeFeature listOfFeatures
    in
    map zipListToPoints normalizedFeatures
    end
```

(SO has messed up the indentation of my SML somewhat, sorry!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lists were regular (each list within a list having the same length), what you describe sounds like a matrix transposition. This is easily achieved using Standard ML's list combinators. For example:

```
fun transpose [] = []
  | transpose (xss as (xs::_)) =
    List.tabulate (length xs, fn row => map (fn xs => List.nth (xs, row)) xss)
```

And a demonstration:

```
- val m = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];
> val m = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] : int list list
- transpose m;
> val it = [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]] : int list list
```

One could adjust this `fn row => map (fn xs => List.nth (xs, row))` helper function to accept if a given row is not full. But if all rows are not equally long, it would need to find the longest of these first in order to avoid throwing away elements on positions greater than the length of the first row.

**Update:** For large matrices, the running time above might not work out. Below is another way to define `transpose` such that previously transposed elements are not visited again and again:

```
(* Written without pattern matching *)
fun transpose [] = []
  | transpose xs =
    if null (hd xs)
    then nil
    else map hd xs :: transpose (map tl xs)

(* Written with pattern matching *)
fun transpose [] = []
  | transpose ([]::_) = []
  | transpose xss = map hd xss :: transpose (map tl xss)
```

Comment: I think that I follow this. One of the reasons I was trying to go this route -- a tail recursive function that walks over both lists -- is that I assumed that List.nth took O(n) time, giving the whole thing... O(m*n^2) time, I think? With n = length(xs) and m = length(xss), since List.nth gets called once for each item in xs for each list in xss. I thought that it would be possible to get the whole thing done in one pass through the list. I'll google around for SML matrix transpose, anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `List.nth` does indeed iterate over the same elements unnecessarily many times. I have provided a version of `transpose` that does not suffer from this.

Answer (score 2):

here's an idea for that inner `zipElement`
all credits go to Dan Grossman

```
exception BadTriple
fun zip3 list_triple =
  case list_triple of
      ([],[],[]) => []
     | (hd1::tl1,hd2::tl2,hd3::tl3) => (hd1,hd2,hd3)::zip3(tl1,tl2,tl3)
     | _ => raise BadTriple
```

i hope you can figure the way to transform the tuple into the list yourself.